# Create a new process from within another process/program

Tags: windows, process, malware

Let's say I have to write a Windows program that will at some time create one or more new processes with the corresponding executable images. I have known a few possible ways to do this:

- The easy way is to extract this image to disk and create a new process from there.
- As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523681/execute-a-process-from-memory-within-another-process) question and its answerer suggested (load the image to a RAM drive like tmpfs - the Windows equivalence is [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/))

My question is: Is there any other way? I'm thinking of somehow turn the exec into a DLL and load it or even trojanized some of the running processes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a virus by the sounds of it... What's wrong with the 2 ways you suggested? Are you trying to inject a dll version of the exe into another running process?

Comment: Actually I'm researching on ways you can create a wrapper/dropper for a malware. Those 2 ways are perfectly legit, but I want to know whether there are any other ways.

Comment: Ok, but be aware that SO doesn't usually take kindly to writing malware, not me personally :) so +1 from me, but just a heads up

Comment: Thanks, this was only a research, mostly for malware analysis, not for writing one though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697292/detecting-reflective-dll-injection

Comment: Wow, thanks. I actually do know vaguely about the VirtualProtect function and how it could be used in this particular case. I'll read up on the links.